# Integrals involving reciprocal square root of a quartic

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

For two integration below, what is the ratio of them? 
$$I_1 = \int_0^1\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^4}}$$  $$I_2 = \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}$$
What is the ration $\frac{I_1}{I_2}$?
I do not have any thoughts for solving this question so could anyone give me some hints?
Thank you!!

Comment: These are both elliptic integrals. $I_{1}$ is a pretty standard integral with value $\dfrac{\pi}{2M(1, \sqrt{2})}$ where $M(a, b)$ denotes arithmetic-geometric mean of two numbers $a, b$.

Comment: The first one is the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in disguise, just let $x=t^4$.

Comment: @Paramanand What do you mean by that? Sorry..I am a college student. Maybe some theorems are not known to me...

Comment: @BoanBowenTAN: Well the integrals involving square roots of third and fourth degree polynomials are called elliptic integrals. They arise while calculating the perimeter of an ellipse (hence such name). You can read more about them in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral About Arithmetic Geometric Mean you can read my blog post http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2009/08/arithmetic-geometric-mean-of-gauss.html

Comment: @Lucian: Almost.  We need to show that the integral on $[0,1]$ is equal to the integral on $[1,\infty)$.  See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1682148).

Comment: For what it's worth, this was Problem 4848 in **American Mathematical Monthly** ["Without performing any integration determine the ratio..."] proposed by [Murray S. Klamkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murray_S._Klamkin) and solved in [67 #3, March 1960), p. 300](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2309717). I came across this web page while looking for more information about what I gave yesterday in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/681893/an-interesting-integral/2734220#2734220) (I'm thinking of trying to evaluate that integral) and I recognized this as an old Monthly problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first one:let $t^2=\sin{x}$,then
$$I_{1}=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}$$

The second one: let
$t^2=\tan{x}$

then
$$I_{2}=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin{x}\cos{x}}}=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}$$
so
$$\dfrac{I_{1}}{I_{2}}=\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: To me this solution seems to be the simplest because it involves very simple substitutions. +1

Comment: This is cool. Normally, one would avoid $\sqrt{\sin(x)}$, but here, it is the thing to do! (+1)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

$$I_1(x)=\int_x^1\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^4}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{\arccos x}\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2}\sin^2u}}$$

$$I_2(x)=\int_0^x \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\arccos\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}}\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2}\sin^2u}}$$

and since $$\arccos 0 = \arccos \frac{1-1^2}{1+1^2}$$

$$\frac{I_1(0)}{I_2(1)}=\sqrt{2}$$

From the hint the substitutions should be pretty straightforward.

---

Added due to the comment below:

The first one: let $t=\cos u$, $u=\arccos t$.

$$\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^4}}=\frac{-\sin udu}{\sqrt{1-\cos^4 u}}=\frac{-\sin udu}{\sqrt{\sin^2 u(1+\cos^2 u)}}$$

and you get the RHS almost immediately.

The second one: let $t=\tan\frac{u}{2}$, $t^2=\frac{1}{\cos^2 \frac{u}{2}}-1=\frac{1-\cos u}{1+\cos u}$, $u=\arccos \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$. Plug it in, and get the RHS also (almost) immediately.

Comment: Here what substitutions did you do??

Comment: Well, I thought you should be able to figure it out yourself. I will extend the answer showing the first one soon.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#00f}{\large I_{1}}&\equiv\int_{0}^{1}{\dd t \over \root{1 - t^{4}}}
=\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t}^{-1/2}\,{1 \over 4}\,t^{-3/4}\,\dd t
={1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}t^{-3/4}\pars{1 - t}^{-1/2}\,\dd t
={1 \over 4}\,{\rm B}\pars{{1 \over 4},\half}
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 4}\,{\Gamma\pars{1/4}\Gamma\pars{1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{3/4}}
={1 \over 4}\,{\Gamma\pars{1/4}\root{\pi} \over \pi/\bracks{\Gamma\pars{1/4}\sin\pars{\pi/4}}}=
\color{#00f}{\large{1 \over 4\root{2\pi}}\,\Gamma^{\,2}\pars{1 \over 4}}
\approx 1.3110
\end{align}

> ${\rm B}\pars{x,y}$ and $\Gamma\pars{z}$ are the *Beta* and *Gamma* functions, respectively. We used well known properties of them.

\begin{align}
\color{#00f}{\large I_{2}}&\equiv\int_{0}^{1}{\dd t \over \root{1 + t^{4}}}
=\half\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd t \over \root{1 + t^{4}}}
\end{align}
Lets $\ds{x \equiv {1 \over 1 + t^{4}}\quad\iff\quad t = \pars{{1 \over x} - 1}^{1/4}}$
\begin{align}
\color{#00f}{\large I_{2}}&=\half\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd t \over \root{1 + t^{4}}}
=\half\int_{1}^{0}x^{1/2}\,{1 \over 4}\,\pars{1 - x \over x}^{-3/4}
\pars{-\,{\dd x \over x^{2}}}
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 8}\int_{0}^{1}x^{-3/4}\pars{1 - x}^{-3/4}\,\dd x
={1 \over 8}\,{\rm B}\pars{{1 \over 4},{1 \over 4}}
={1 \over 8}\,{\Gamma\pars{1/4}\Gamma\pars{1/4} \over \Gamma\pars{1/2}}
\\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{\large{1 \over 8\root{\pi}}\,\Gamma^{\,2}\pars{1 \over 4}}
\approx 0.9270
\end{align}

> $$
> \color{#00f}{\large{I_{1} \over I_{2}}} = {1/\pars{4\root{2}} \over 1/8}
> =\color{#00f}{\large\root{2}}
> $$

Answer (score 1):

As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/86553),
$$
\int_0^1t^{\alpha-1}\,(1-t)^{\beta-1}\,\mathrm{d}t
=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}
$$
and
$$
\int_0^\infty t^{\alpha-1}\,(1+t)^{-\beta}\,\mathrm{d}t
=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta-\alpha)}{\Gamma(\beta)}
$$
Substituting $t\mapsto1/t$ and then $t\mapsto t^{1/4}$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}
&=\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}\\
&=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}\\
&=\frac18\int_0^\infty t^{-3/4}(1+t)^{-1/2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac18\frac{\Gamma(1/4)^2}{\Gamma(1/2)}
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1-t^4}}
&=\frac14\int_0^1t^{-3/4}(1-t)^{-1/2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac14\frac{\Gamma(1/4)\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(3/4)}
\end{align}
$$
As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176216), $\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)=\pi\csc(\pi x)$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1-t^4}}}{\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}}
&=2\frac{\Gamma(1/2)^2}{\Gamma(1/4)\Gamma(3/4)}\\
&=2\frac{\pi\csc(\pi/2)}{\pi\csc(\pi/4)}\\[12pt]
&=\sqrt2
\end{align}
$$