# Trig substitution for integral of $z/(x^2+z^2)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I have an integral $\int_1^4\int_y^4\int_0^z\frac{z}{x^2+z^2}\,dx\,dz\,dy$ but I can't figure out what trig substitution to use on the first step. When I try $z=\cos$ and $x=\sin$, I end up with $\int\cos$ but the book comes up with $z\cdot\frac{1}{z}\cdot\arctan \frac{x}{z}$ so I know I screwed up.

Can someone show me how the book took this step?

Thanks!

Comment: Try rewriting the integral with dz as the first integration

Comment: My textbook takes the integral in this order, though, so I'm trying to figure out what they did. They have a habit of skipping multiple steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The innermost integral is with respect to $x$, treating $z$ as a constant.

Since this is the case, you might as well go with: $$ x = z\tan\theta \implies \text{d}x = z \sec^2\theta \text{ d}\theta \qquad (*)$$ $$ x = 0 \implies \theta = 0, \ x = z \implies \theta = \dfrac{\pi}{4} $$

> $$ \int_{0}^{z} \dfrac{z}{x^2+z^2} \text{ d}x = \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \dfrac{z}{z^2 \sec^2\theta} \ z\sec^2\theta \text{ d}\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{4} $$

---

In the case of the indefinite integral, we have that:

> $$ \begin{aligned} \int \dfrac{z}{x^2+z^2} \text{ d}x \ \overset{(*)}= \ \int \dfrac{z}{z^2 \sec^2\theta} \ z\sec^2\theta \text{ d}\theta \ = \int z \dfrac{1}{z} \text{ d}\theta \ & = \ z \dfrac{1}{z} \theta + \mathcal{C} \ = \ z \dfrac{1}{z} \arctan \left( \dfrac{x}{z} \right) + \mathcal{C} \end{aligned} $$

Comment: That's an elegant solution but it doesn't show me how the book arrived at their particular solution. I'm trying to follow their methods in this case, so I'm trying to come out with their same indefinite solution.

Comment: I think it's exactly the same, but they considered the indefinite integral.

Comment: Check out my edit, @PoGaMi.

Comment: I worked the indefinite out on paper given your substitution and I get your same answer, which is integral(1), but I don't see where their arctan came from.

Comment: From our substitution: $$ x=z\tan\theta \implies \theta = \arctan \left( \frac{x}{z} \right) $$

Comment: Ooooohhhhh, I think I see. So the integral $\int1d\theta=\theta=\arctan\frac{x}{z}$. Thanks for being patient with me!

Comment: Exactly, @PoGaMi. You got it! (Don't forget the constant of integration)

Comment: As a side note, did you know to use that trig sub from experience or are there standard rules? I took Calc 2 about 8yrs ago, so I'm a bit lost in this part of Calc 3.

Comment: It helped to see an arctan in your answer, but if I ever see something like $bx^2 + c$, I usually try some kind of trig sub to exploit the Pythagorean identities.

Comment: @PoGaMi In regards to your last question just above, on how to select the best trig substitution, you might want to take a look at my answer to another question, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381257/trigonometric-substitution-and-triangles/1381269#1381269).