# Proving a quadratic polynomial has no real roots without using derivatives or any formulas

Tags: roots, quadratics

How do I prove that a quadratic polynomial has no real root without the use of any derivatives or formulas? The specific equation is $$x^2-6x+10=0$$

Comment: Complete the square? By the way, I don't see how derivatives would help.

Comment: "*I don't see how derivatives would help*" Well, maybe one can use the [Racetrack principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racetrack_principle) with $x^2$ and $6x-10$ for the values of $x$ where $y = 6x - 10$ lies above the $x$-axis . . .

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Find the absolute minimum and show that it's positive . . .

Comment: @Noah Schweber: [Oh . . .](https://cache-blog.credit.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/overlooked.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

$x^2-6x+10=x^2-6x+9+1=(x-3)^2+1>0$ for all real numbers $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way without completing the square.

Subtracting $10$ from both sides gives $x^2 - 6x = -10,$ which can be rewritten as $x(x-6) = -10.$ Now use the variable change $y = x-3$ (note that $x-3$ is the midpoint of $x$ and $x-6)$ to symmetrize the equation, getting $(y+3)(y-3) = -10.$ Expanding, we get $y^2 - 9 = -10,$ and adding $10$ to both sides gives $y^2 = -1,$ which has no real solution. (Note that if there *had been* a real solution for $x,$ say $x = r,$ then $y=r+3$ would be a real solution for $y.)$

Comment: Note that using the variable change y = x + 3, then x - 6 = [(y - 3) - 6] = y - 9 instead.

Comment: @Mick: Thanks! I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: By completing the square.

Answer (score 1):

**Without formulas**:

The equation is that of a parabola with a vertical axis and the vertex is at coordinates obtained by completing the square. After using this transformation of the expression, you will notice that it is strictly positive.