# Reference request on quartic equation

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I have the following polynomial in $s$
$$\omega_4 s^4+\omega_3 s^3+\omega_2 s^2+\omega_1 s+\omega_0=0$$
where $\omega_i\in \mathbb R$ for $i=0,\dots,4$. This is a quartic equation and, as we can se on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function), there is a formula due to the italian mathematician Lodovico Ferrari.

Wikipedia article is very clear but I need also other types of references, like textbooks, papers etc. I read the references suggested by the above webpage but they are not as clear as Wikipedia.

Comment: See here http://article.sciencepublishinggroup.com/pdf/10.11648.j.acm.20130202.11.pdf

Comment: For one method (there are several methods), see the references I give in Section 3: *Quadratic Factors of* $\;x^4 + 10x^2 - 96x - 71$ in [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/681893/how-to-integrate-int-fracx-sqrtx410x2-96x-71dx/2734220#2734220).

Answer (score 4):

I suggest the third chapter (“Quartic equations”) of Jean-Pierre Tignol's *Galois' Theory of Algebraic Equations*.