# Factoring Quartics (in quadratic form)

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I have some quartic polynomial I wish to factor.
Here is an example:

> $x^4 + x^2 + 1 $

I know the answer to this question

> $ (x^2 + x + 1)(x^2 -x +1) $

We get these 2 irreducible quadratics.
I am trying to see if there is some systematic way, a process to arrive at this, without having to figure out a pattern for this.

Comment: Such a systematic way is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_cubic#Factoring_quartic_polynomials).

Comment: Follow the link in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2854752/reference-request-on-quartic-equation#comment5888346_2854752).

Comment: Best to include an actual question, followed by a question mark.  Something like "Could I get some tips on how to work from the original, to arrive at the answer?"  Or "What is it about the quartic that suggests how to proceed to factor it?  Or any question you intend to ask.

Comment: Hi amWhy, you did a good job re-phrasing my question in general. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have this nice sort of symmetry there's a trick you can apply;
divide through by $x^2, x\ne 0$ to get $$x^2 + 1 + \frac{1}{x^2} = \left(x + \frac{1}{x}\right)^2 -1$$

Using the substitution $u=x + 1/x$ allows you to solve for the roots of the polynomial.

Something else you could do: take the polynomials $ax^2 + bx + c$ and $dx^2+ex + f$, multiply them together and solve for $a,b,c,d,e,f$. Note that you'll end up with 6 unknowns and 5 equations, so you'll have to choose one of the values (say $a=1$).

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply.  That is interesting, in terms of trying to go further with this to find the roots. But I was asking how to go thru a systematic process to get the quartic factored down to those 2 irreducible quadratics, if there is such a way.

Comment: OK Quanta, I think i briefly misunderstood you, i thought you were reducing the irreducible. I will try this method of yours, and see what i get.

Comment: Hi Quanta, I tried it out. That is quite an ingenious approach/trick. I will give you as the answer to my question, only because it is a clever trick. BUT i hope others will put another possible approach to this question as well.

Comment: I added some more, you might find it useful

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the differences of squares identity just as below:
$$x^4+x^2+1=x^4+2x^2+1-x^2$$
The first three summands is conveniently $(x^2+1)^2$ and the equation can be rewritten into:
$$(x^2+1)^2-x^2$$
and by differences of squares identity you would get your two quadratics.

Comment: That is really great MathEnthusiast!!! I wish I could vote for more than one solution as the solution. Both you and Quantaliinuxite, deserve to be the solutions to this problem i presented here, unfortunately, I can't assign 2 solutions. Thanks once again for this amazing solutions here.