# How to factor polynomials of degree larger than $2$?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

For instance, how do you factor a polynomial like $x^4+x^2+1$?

Secondly, is there any variation to the technique if it was a larger degree or not of the specific form I specified above?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90790/discussion-on-question-by-cantcauchy-how-to-factor-polynomials-of-degree-larger).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^4+x^2+1=x^4+2x^2+1-x^2=(x^2+1)^2-x^2=(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1).$$
There is also the following way.
$$(x^2-1)(x^4+x^2+1)=x^6-1=(x^3-1)(x^3+1)=(x^2-1)(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1).$$

Comment: +1 OK, I guess you were writing this when HAMIDINE SOUMARE's answer showed up . . .

Comment: @can'tcauchy There are harder problems. For example: $x^4+4x-1.$

Comment: By the way, this harder problem can be handled by a generalization of the method which I discussed in the answer I cited in another comment.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^4+x^2+1=x^4+x^2+1+x^2-x^2$$
$$=x^4+2x^2+1-x^2=(x^2+1)^2-x^2$$
$$=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$

Comment: Also +1, because although you were later than Aleksas Domarkas, you somewhat explain how to obtain the factorization.

Comment: what happened to the $x^4$ term in the second equality ?

Comment: ah okay , no I get you thanks :)

Comment: Edited @can'tcauchy

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=x^2$

Then
$$x^4+x^2=1$$
$$=z^2+z+1$$
Using the quadratic formula to solve when $az^2+bz+c$ equals zero
$$z=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
gives
$$z^2+z+1=0$$
when
$$z=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{-3}}{2}$$
$$z=\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt3i }{2}$$
Thus
$$z^2+z+1=\big(z-\frac{-1+\sqrt3i}{2}\big) \big(z-\frac{-1-\sqrt3i}{2}\big)$$
$$x^4+x^2+1=\big(x^2-\frac{-1+\sqrt3i}{2}\big) \big(x^2-\frac{-1-\sqrt3i}{2}\big)$$
This can be taken further...

Comment: I think you inadvertently left out square root signs in front of $3$'s

Comment: Thanks ! Popped them in, just.

Answer (score -2):

$$x^4+x^2+1=(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1)$$

Solving details: use method of undetermined coefficients
$${{x}^{4}}+{{x}^{2}}+1=\left( {{x}^{2}}+a x+1\right) \, \left( {{x}^{2}}+b x+1\right) $$
$\Rightarrow$
$$a+b=0,\quad ab+2=1$$
$\Rightarrow$
$$a=1,\;b=-1$$  or  $$ a=-1,\;b=1$$

Comment: how is this a method?

Comment: ... although for this particular example, that's clever !

Comment: +1 You beat me to it, although apparently someone downvoted you, maybe because you didn't explain how the factorization is obtained (the question)? Anyway, for the OP, regarding quartics like this, see "3. Quadratic Factors of $\;x^4 + 10x^2 - \; 96x - 71$" in my first answer to [How to integrate $ \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^4+10x^2-96x-71}}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/681893).

Comment: I was looking more for the method, theres online calculators to factorise these things but I wouldn't have one in an exam and I'm not experienced enough to eyeball an answer

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg
With method of undetermined coefficients:
$x^4+4x-1=(x^2-\sqrt{2}x+\sqrt2+1)(x^2+\sqrt2x-\sqrt2+1)$