# How do you rewrite a polynomial for factorization when the application of a special product/algebraic formula doesn't seem self-evident?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

I want to factorize the polynomial $9a^4-a^2+16$. $(3a^2+5a+4)(3a^2-5a+4)$ is the solution according to the book, but it doesn't provide a step-by-step solution. I tried the PhotoMath app, and the first step according to it was to rewrite the expression in the following way:

$9a^4-15a^3+15a^3+12a^2-25a^2+12a^2+20a-20a+16$

The problem is, unlike some other easier expressions, the application of a special product/algebraic formula doesn't seem self-evident to me in this case.

There could be many ways I could rewrite such polynomials, but I don't want to waste time in my exams. I just wanna figure out the correct way to rewrite the expression just by looking at it and applying an algorithm instead of brainstorming infinite ways. What's the algorithm for rewriting a polynomial for factorization in cases like these?

Comment: I hope you realize that the great majority of polynomials **cannot** be factored so there cannot be a general algorithm.

Comment: This happens to be a semi-standard type that I discuss (with two simple examples) and give several references to in "*3. Quadratic Factors of* $\;x^4 + 10x^2 - \; 96x - 71$" of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2734220/13130). You'll need to scroll down a bit to get to Section 3 of that answer.

Comment: There is a a [polynomial factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) and a [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) that may help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to write it as a product of two polinomials (with unknow coefficents) both of degree 2 or one of degree 1 and second of degree 3. $$9x^4-x^2+16 = (ax^2+bx+c)(dx^2+ex+f)$$ and try to find the coefficients. Multiply those terms in bracket and do a sutable comparisons, say $ad = 9$, $ae+bd=0$,...

If there is no slution to this system then try

$$9x^4-x^2+16 = (ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)(ex+f)$$
and do the same again.

In general it could happen that you won't get a solution to second also which means that given polynomial is irreducibile.

Answer (score 1):

First and third terms remaind me on $x^2+2xy+y^2$ with $2xy$ left. So what do I have to add?

\begin{align}
\color{blue}{9a^4}-a^2+\color{blue}{16} &= \color{blue}{9a^4}+\color{red}{24a^2}+\color{blue}{16}-a^2-\color{red}{24a^2} \\
&=(3a^2+4)^2-25a^2\\
&= \Big((3a^2+4)-5a\Big)\Big((3a^2+4)+5a\Big)
\end{align}

Comment: You don't have to accept my answer, you can upvote it though. See and wait what others will say.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Really appreciate it!