# How to apply Risch's algorithm to $\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^4-2x^3+3x^2+4x+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, differential-algebra

It is known that $$\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^4-2x^3+3x^2+4x+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x=$$ $$-\frac{1}{6}\log\Big((2x^4-10x^3+24x^2-28x+14)\sqrt{x^4-2x^3+3x^2+4x+1}-2x^6+12x^5-36x^4+56x^3-42x^2+13\Big)+C.$$

To get this result, I tried to apply Risch's algorithm as described in Manuel Bronstein's [*Symbolic Integration Tutorial*](http://www-sop.inria.fr/cafe/Manuel.Bronstein/publications/issac98.pdf), as follows. The integrand is $xy/D$ where $y^2=D=x^4-2x^3+3x^2+4x+1$ is square-free, so the indefinite integral has only a logarithm part, and we then get to section 2.5. There a procedure is described, which in step 3 computes the polynomial $$R(t)=\mathrm{Resultant}_x(\mathrm{Resultant}_y(xy-t\frac{\mathrm{d}D}{\mathrm{d}x},y^2-D),D).$$
From this formula, we have $R(t)=186624t^8$ for the given integrand. This has no nonzero roots, so by step 6 the integral is not elementary. This contradicts the antiderivative result given above. **What is wrong?**

Comment: I don't know the specifics of Risch's algorithm nor have time now to look into this, but possibly the work I did in my extensive answer to the following less specific question about  a similar integral could be of use: [How to integrate $ \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^4+10x^2-96x-71}}dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/681893/13130)

Comment: @dave-l-renfro  The integral can be reduced to elliptic functions using the standard procedure you mentioned. However, the integral is actually pseudo-elliptic, so I need a procedure that can identify pseudo-elliptic integrals. Thus I am asking how to apply Risch's algorithm which claims to work.