# Trigonometric Substitutions related to Elliptic Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution, elliptic-integrals

Recently while studying Elliptic Integrals and related topics I have come across various Interesting Trigonometric Substitutions, examples given below

1.

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2(\sin t)^4}}\ dt=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x-2x(\sin v)^2}}\ dv$$

which uses the substitution

$$v=\arctan(\sqrt{1+x}\tan t)$$

2. The well known Landen's Transformation
   $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}(\sin t)^2}}\ dt=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1+x\right)^{2}-4x(\sin v)^2}}\ dv$$
   which uses the substitution

$$2v=t+\arcsin(x\sin t)$$

3. Landen's Transformation but different proof

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\cos t)^2+x^2(\sin t)^2}}\ dt=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+x)^2-(1-x)^2(\sin v)^2}}\ dv$$

which uses the substitution

$$t=\arctan\left(\frac{\tan v+\sec v}{\sqrt{x}}\right)$$

4. Gauss's Substitution for Invariance of Cayley Elliptic Integral under AGM

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(a\cos t)^2+(b\sin t)^2}}\ dt=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\frac{a+b}{2}\cos v)^2+(\sqrt{ab}\sin v)^2}}\ dv$$
which uses the substitution

$$\sin t=\frac{2a\sin v}{a+b+(a-b)(\sin v)^2}$$

These are the only examples I could recall right now but there would be many others.

As I am inexperienced in these types of substitutions, to me all of them feel like they were pulled out of thin air.

Even after the substitutions a good amount of algebraic manipulations are needed.

Is there a standard way I can learn and understand all of these substitutions and why they work?

Comment: Possibly some of the references at the end of [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2758902/13130) could help.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you, that is such a nice post. I was able to reduce the first substitution to $$t\to\frac{1-v}{1+vx}$$ which you have covered.