# Two question on Binomial distribution and log-concave?

Tags: probability, analysis, discrete-mathematics, binomial-distribution

I'm looking for a proof that the density of the Binomial Distribution is discrete log-concave. I found many mentions of it but couldn't find a complete proof.

In addition, Can I say that $f(x)=\mathbb{P}(\text{Bin}(n,p)\geq x)$ is also log-concave?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show your attempt?

Comment: Have a look at (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834786/log-concavity-of-binomial-coefficients-binomnk2-geq-binomnk-1-bin)