# The integral $\int_{\varepsilon}^1 r^n(1-r)^{k-n}\,dr $

Tags: integration

We know from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86542/prove-binomnk-1-n1-int-01xk1-xn-kdx-for-0-leq-k-le/86578#86578) that for $0\leq n \leq k$,
$$
\int_0^1 r^n(1-r)^{k-n}\,dr = \frac{1}{(k+1)\dbinom k n}.
$$

In my case, $n$ and $k$ are integers.

But what is

$$
\int_{\varepsilon}^1 r^n(1-r)^{k-n}\,dr 
$$

for small $0 < \varepsilon$ ?

This question comes from the comments to the accepted answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/903516/66307 .

Comment: Approximately $\int_0^1 r^n(1-r)^{k-n}\,dr = \frac{1}{(k+1)\dbinom k n}.$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I added an explanation for where this comes from. I assume it is different enough to make the mean finite in that linked question. Does this make more sense?

Comment: I was joking. I take it you want to estimate the value of the integral asymptotically as $\varepsilon \to 0$?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Michael Hardy's answer does a better at explaining the question than I did. The only problem with it is that I am worried the bound he gives might be very loose.

Comment: @Travis See my comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usng a CAS, the following result was obtained $$\int_{a}^1 r^n(1-r)^{k-n}\,dr=\frac{\Gamma (n+1) \Gamma (k-n+1)}{\Gamma (k+2)}-\frac{a^{n+1} \,
   _2F_1(n+1,n-k;n+2;a)}{n+1}$$ You can expand the hypergeometric function as a Taylor series and then get as an approximation $$\frac{a^n \left(-\frac{\Gamma (k+2) a}{n+1}+\frac{(k-n) \Gamma (k+2)
   a^2}{n+2}+O\left(a^3\right)\right)+\Gamma (n+1) \Gamma (k-n+1)}{\Gamma (k+2)}$$

**Added later**

$$\int_{a}^1 r^n(1-r)^{k-n}\,dr=\frac{1}{(k+1)\dbinom k n}-B_a(n+1,k-n+1)$$ Expanded as a series built at $a=0$, $$B_a(n+1,k-n+1)=a^{n+1} \left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{(n-k) a}{n+2}+\frac{(n-k) (n-k+1) a^2}{2
   (n+3)}+O\left(a^3\right)\right)$$

Comment: What does $O(a^3)$ mean? In computer science the O notation requires a variable which is going to infinity. But $a$ is bounded by $1$.

Comment: $O(a^n)$ (the big O notation) describes the limiting behavior of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value

Answer (score 1):

- The [incomplete beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function). That's what “this” is. For $\epsilon=0$, see [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).
- For $k-n\in\mathbb N,~$ just expand $(1-r)^{k-n}$ using the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).
- For $k-n\not\in\mathbb N,~$ and $n\in\mathbb N,~$ let $r=1-t$, in which case your second term becomes $1-r$ $=t.~$ Now expand $(1-t)^n$.
- For $\{n\}=\{k-n\}=\dfrac12$, use [trigonometric substitutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution), where $~\{x\}~$ denotes the [fractional part](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) of *x*.

Comment: Thank you. I should have specified, $n$ and $k$ are integers and we are in your case 2.

Answer (score 0):

In the earlier question we consider a random variable $P$ uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and a sequence $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ that were conditionally independent given $P$, and conditional on $P$ each $X_i$ is equal to $1$ with probability $P$ and $0$ otherwise.  Then we considered the random variable $K=\min\{k\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\} : X_1+\cdots+X_k=n\}$.  The probability distribution of $K$ was found to be given by $\Pr(K=k)=n/(k(k+1))$ for $k=n,n+1,n+2,\ldots.$  Finally, it was found that $\mathbb E(K)=\infty$.

The question was posed in comments, whether $\mathbb E(K)$ would be finite if $P$ had been distributed uniformly on $[\varepsilon,1]$ for some $\varepsilon>0$.

I will answer that here.  That doesn't fully answer the question as posed above, but perhaps that is what is of interest.

So suppose $P$ is distributed uniformly on $[\varepsilon,1]$ and $0<\varepsilon\le 1$.  Then
$$
\mathbb E(K) = \mathbb E(\mathbb E(K\mid P)) \overset{(1)}{\le} \mathbb E(K\mid P=\varepsilon) \overset{(2)} = \frac n \varepsilon. 
$$
The equality $(2)$ is well known.  I will leave the proofs of $(1)$ and $(2)$ as an exercise for now.  Maybe more later$\ldots\ldots$.

Comment: Well that is another lovely answer but this time full of mysteries :) Details for the missing parts would be great! It would also be great to understand how loose that bound is.

Comment: For $(2)$, google "negative binomial distribution".