# Finding sum of $\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq n} \binom{n}{i}$ and $\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq n}\binom{n}{j}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Finding sum of
\begin{align}
\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq n}\binom{n}{i} \tag1\\
\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq n}\binom{n}{j} \tag2
\end{align}

For $(1)$, we can write it as
\begin{align}
\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq n}\binom{n}{i} 1^j &= 1^1\binom{n}{0}+1^2\left[\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}\right]+1^3\left[\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}\right]+\cdots+\left[\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\cdots +\binom{n}{n-1}\right] \\
&=n\binom{n}{0}+(n-1)\binom{n}{1}+(n-2)\binom{n}{2}+\cdots +\binom{n}{n-1}
\end{align}

How do I solve it after that?

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1060419/42969

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A finite binomial sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060419/a-finite-binomial-sum)

Comment: But in that question , only one  variable and here  we have $2$ variables $i$ and $j$

Comment: Hey @jacky $$ \sum_{0 \leq i \leq j \leq n} \binom{n}{j} = \sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=i}^n \binom{n}{j}  ?$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq n}\binom{n}{i}=$$
$$n\binom{n}{0}+(n-1)\binom{n}{1}+(n-2)\binom{n}{2}+\cdots +\binom{n}{n-1}=$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}(n-i)\binom{n}{i}=
\sum_{i=0}^{n}(n-i)\binom{n}{n-i}=
\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\binom{n}{k}=n2^{n-1},$$
see, for instance, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060419/a-finite-binomial-sum) for the last equality.

Also
$$\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq n}\binom{n}{j}=\sum_{j=0}^{n}j\binom{n}{j}=n2^{n-1}.$$

Comment: $$ \sum_{0 \leq i \leq j \leq n} \binom{n}{j} = \sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=i}^n \binom{n}{j}  ?? $$ I am confused in this. Please tell me.

Comment: @LuckyChouhan I interpeted the expression $\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq n}\binom{n}{j}$ as that each summand $\binom{n}{j}$ is taken as many times as there are integers $i$ such that $0\le i<j$, that is $j$ many times.

Comment: Oh, Now I got. Thank you Alex!

Answer (score 3):

As you have done
$$\sum_{0 \leq i \leq j \leq n} \binom{n}{i} = n\binom{n}{0} + (n-1)\binom{n}{1} + \cdots + \binom{n}{n-1}$$
Now we can rewrite it as
$$\sum_{0 \leq i \leq j \leq n} \binom{n}{i} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (n-i) \binom{n}{i} \tag{1}$$

We can also increase index of summation which is in RHS of $(1)$ because $(n-n)=0$ so,

$$\sum_{0 \leq i \leq j \leq n} \binom{n}{i} = \sum_{i=0}^{n} (n-i) \binom{n}{i} \tag{2}$$
$$\sum_{0 \leq i \leq j \leq n} \binom{n}{i} = n \underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i}}_{s_1} - \underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^{n} i \binom{n}{i} }_{s_2}
\tag{3}$$

Now we can easily find closed form for both summations in $(3)$, for that you can either see the linked questions in comments or use
$$ (1+x)^n = \sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i} x^i  \tag{4} $$

Differentiate both sides of $(4)$ we get,
$$ n (1+x)^n = \sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i} i x^{i-1}  $$

Now you can easily find the values of $s_1$ and $s_2$.