# integration of $(1-x)^mx^n$ from $0$ to $1$, $m$ and $n$ positive integers

Tags: calculus

trying to integrate $\int_0^1 (1-x)^m x^n dx$, $m$ and $n$ positive integers. I know the answer is a fraction containing gamma functions but don't know how to get there

Comment: also trying to show equality of this integral with (1-x)^n*x^m same interval

Comment: @brayton Showing equality is trivial. Just substitute $y=1-x$.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach, that is closely related to the Beta function, is to integrate by parts, assuming $m\gt0$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1(1-x)^mx^n\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-\frac1{n+1}\int_0^1(1-x)^m\,\mathrm{d}x^{n+1}\\
&=\frac1{n+1}\int_0^1x^{n+1}\,\mathrm{d}(1-x)^m\\
&=\frac{m}{n+1}\int_0^1(1-x)^{m-1}x^{n+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
We can iterate $(1)$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1(1-x)^mx^n\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac{m}{n+1}\frac{m-1}{n+2}\cdots\frac1{n+m}\int_0^1x^{n+m}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{m}{n+1}\frac{m-1}{n+2}\cdots\frac1{n+m}\frac1{n+m+1}\\
&=\frac{n!\,m!}{(n+m+1)!}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(m+1)}{\Gamma(n+m+2)}\\[6pt]
&=\mathrm{B}(n+1,m+1)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
If $m=0$, then $(2)$ does not need iteration.

In fact, the [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) is often defined as
$$
\mathrm{B}(x,y)=\int_0^1t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{3}
$$

Comment: @robjon Very straightforward and elegant!  Integrate by parts and iterate.  It's interesting to see the identity presented from our solutions.  Maybe I should post a question asking others for ways to prove the equivalence.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Dr.MV: When I first came across the Beta function, I did just as above to get the values on the integers. Then I extended it to general $x,y$ as in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/86553). A question about the various methods to show the equivalence would be interesting, but might meet with resistance from some due to the warning on [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) not to ask questions like “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”

Comment: That is interesting.  The only time I used the Beta function was in numerically solving an integro-differential equation.  The method I used, if memory serves (this was 20 years ago), involved converting the continuous operator equation into a matrix equation.  The elements of the matrix were obtained as closed form integrals, including the Beta function.

Answer (score 1):

Using the binomial expansion, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 (1-x)^m x^n dx&=\int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k} (-1)^kx^k x^n dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k} (-1)^k \int_0^1  x^{k+n} dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+n+1}
\end{align}$$

Of course, we could write the binomial coefficient in terms of the gamma function as

$$\binom{m}{k}=\frac{\Gamma(m+1)}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(m+1-k)}$$