# Beta and Gamma functions relation proof.

Tags: solution-verification

I found a proof of the Beta-Gamma functions relation, but I don't understand what happened between 3rd and 2nd last line. There was s^z and in the next line there is s^(z-1). Where did it come from? Or is the proof incorrect?

Can anyone explain it, please?

[See the proof here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYZU0.png)

$$\int_0^\infty s^z \ e^{-s}$$
becomes
$$\int_0^\infty s^{z-1} \ e^{-s}$$

Comment: Change integration variables via $r:=wz$ to get the Gamma function definition, and you'll get a $1/z$ term,

Comment: $$\int_0^\infty s^z \ e^{-s} $$ becomes 
$$\int_0^\infty s^{z-1} \ e^{-s}$$
Why? Where did that -1 next to z come from

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/86553) covers the same equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are asking about the line
$$
\begin{align}
&\phantom{=\ }\int_0^\infty s^ze^{-s}\int_0^\infty(us)^{w-1}e^{-su}\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}s\\
&=\int_0^\infty s^{z-1}e^{-s}\,\Gamma(w)\,\mathrm{d}s
\end{align}
$$
That is because, using the substitution $u\mapsto\frac ts$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty(us)^{w-1}e^{-su}\,\mathrm{d}u
&=\int_0^\infty t^{w-1}e^{-t}\frac1s\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac1s\,\Gamma(w)
\end{align}
$$