# An integral inside an integral turns into a product of two integrals?

Tags: definite-integrals, gamma-function, beta-function

I am struggling to see how after substituting this:
$$\frac{1}{(1+u)^{a+b}}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(a+b)}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(1+u)t}t^{a+b-1}dt$$
into this:
$$B(a,b)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{u^{a-1}}{(1+u)^{a+b}}du$$
I will get this:
$$B(a,b)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(a+b)}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}t^{a+b-1}dt\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ut}u^{a-1}du$$
because all I have is this:
$$B(a,b)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(a+b)}\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{a-1}\left[\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(1+u)t}t^{a+b-1}dt\right]du$$

Is there a lot of omitted steps here or is there a trick I am failing to catch onto?

The is a part of the derivation on p.25 of this [note](http://mhtlab.uwaterloo.ca/courses/me755/web_chap1.pdf) relating the Beta function to the Gamma function.

Edit:

I give up... I still don't understand but I am starting to seriously question the correctness/necessity of the step mentioned above in the derivation. I think a much more straightforward approach is to multiple left and right side of:
$$B(a,b)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{u^{a-1}}{(1-u)^{a+b}}du$$
by the left and right side of:
$${\Gamma(a+b)}=(1+u)^{a+b}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(1+u)t}t^{a+b-1}dt$$
respectively. Then with the change of variable $k=(1+u)t$, arrive at essentially step 2 of the proof linked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86542/prove-binomnk-1-n1-int-01xk1-xn-kdx-for-0-leq-k-le/86553#86553).

Comment: Both of your expressions for $B(a,b)$ are iterated integrals. Notice the $t$ in both integrands ($e^{-t} t^{a+b-1}$ and $e^{-ut}$)

Comment: You have a mistake (typo?) in the integral representation of the beta function. The denominator is $(1+u)^{a+b}$. Also, check out [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_to_the_gamma_function) for a different proof of this property.

Comment: @bjorn93 Thanks for pointing out the typo. Fixed it!

Comment: It's a typo. The third equation doesn't even make sense as written because the dummy variable $t$ appears outside of the integral where it's defined. Instead the $dt$ is supposed to be after the second integral, not before it. So it's not a product of integrals. (Physicists also like to put differentials before integrands, but that's not what's going on here.)

Comment: @runway44 So you mean the more appropriate way of writing it would be: $$B(a,b)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(a+b)}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}t^{a+b-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ut}u^{a-1}dudt$$ I copied the equation as shown in the original question straight from the notes... guess I should take course notes with a grain of salt here on out

Comment: Yes, the typo is in the original notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hidden step is a change in the order of integration:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{a-1}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(1+u)t}t^{a+b-1}\,dt\right)du=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty u^{a-1}e^{-(1+u)t}t^{a+b-1}\,du\,dt\\
=\int_0^\infty t^{a+b-1}e^{-t}\left(\int_0^\infty u^{a-1}e^{-ut}\,du\right)dt$$
Then, the substitution $u\mapsto u/t$ shows that
$$\int_0^\infty u^{a-1}e^{-ut}\,du=\frac{\Gamma(a)}{t^a} $$
and we're left with
$$\Gamma(a)\int_0^\infty t^{b-1}e^{-t}\,dt=\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b) $$

Edit: I noticed that in the title you mention a product of two integrals. The way the desired result is written could possibly be parsed as a product of integrals but if that were the case, then the equality would be wrong. The correct interpretation should be iterated integration.

Comment: In other words $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}t^{a+b-1}dt\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ut}u^{a-1}du$$ should be understood as iterated integration and not a product of integrals. Got it! Thanks